# See /var/log/messages of one host in another host's messages file

Tags: linux

Seeing /var/log/messages of one host in another's messages file. I checked rsyslog.conf file and nothing seems unsuspicious. What is happening here and how to proceed fixing this issue?

Comment: One of the `syslogd` family is configured to send the messages across the network to a host that's also configured to receive them. What OS and/or distribution is each system running?

Comment: Both hosts are on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)

Comment: Have you checked with colleagues to see if one of them set this up? Go to another RHEL 6.10 system, one that doesn't send its messages on. On it and these other two RHEL systems, run `find /etc/*syslog* -type f | sort | xargs md5sum`. Are the results identical? If not, compare the files that are different. Post them here if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I only checked rsyslog.conf on the receiving end and not sending host. Really appreciate all the response.

Answer (score -1):

you can check for any syslog-ng running on the source host that is sending the logs.

and try to stop it and check if the logs is still appearing on the other host .

because it seems some syslog process is running to send Logs to the other host

best way to check syslog-ng[netstat -ntlp | grep syslog]
and then kill the process using PID [kill -9 PID ]